# dataTable header shorter than table width

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I've been working on this issue and can't seem to find a solution. Within my table if I add one particular column it for some reason throws of the header of the table making the header much smaller than the table width. Here is a screen capture:

[image: Screen Capture of Issue]

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
function callDT() {
var url = "localhost/dataTable001.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){

    var dt = data.dt;
    var table = '<table id="dataTables001"><thead><tr><th>Time</th><th>Number of Cases</th><th>Passed</th><th>Failed</th><th>Class Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    $.each(data.dt.time, function(i, time) {
            table +="<tr class='even gradeC'><td>"+ time + "</td>"+"<td class='priorityColor'>" + data.dt.total[i]  + "</td>"+"<td class='statusColor'>" + data.dt.pass[i] + "</td>"+"<td class='Color'>" + data.dt.fail[i] + "</td>"+"<td class='statusColor'>" + data.dt.class_name[i] + "</td>"+"</tr>";
    });
// after the loop, close your tbody and table tags
table += '</tbody></table>';
// then AFTER the loop, you set the data to the table.
$("#dataTables001").html( table )
$('#dataTables001').dataTable( {

             "paginate": false,
             "scrollY": "260px",
             "info": false,
             "orderFixed": [[0,'desc']],
```

The column that seems to throw everything off is "Class Name". It does contain values of longer lengths. If I take the Class Name column out of the table everything aligns correctly.

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: Does taking out "Time" also fix this.  To me it seems like "Time" header should be a greater width and it would allow all the other columns to align if it was.

Comment: I would really like to see the produced HTML markup ...?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate ID's which I am guessing is the problem.

You are inserting the html into `#dataTables001` ( not sure what that existing element is) and within your new html the main table has the same ID.

If the existing element is a `<table>` then all you need to do is remove the new  table open and close tags

Comment: +1, very good observation. However, I doubt this is the real problem.

Comment: Yes good looking out. I made the change and the problem still persists

Comment: @davidkonrad numerous factors involved though... might be simple css margin, table in a table etc. Plugin definitely will be called on outer element leaving inner doing unexpected things

Comment: @Jason is table properly contained in it's parent? Or is there overflow that could be causing issues? Any css width constraints set on th, td or table itself?

Comment: @charlietfl, there has been numerous questions like this. It typically ends up in malformed HTML. But cant be sure, off course. But you pointed out an issue that certainly _has_ to be fixed anyway!